# Why do LDS members (Mormons) maintain a long-term supply of food?

Tags: lds, eschatology, diet

I understand that LDS members are encouraged to build and maintain a long-term supply of food and other essentials.  From where did this teaching originate and what is the reasoning behind this practice?  What is the prevalent "target" that one is encouraged to achieve?

Does this have anything to do with LDS end-times theology?

Comment: The joke my dad always made was that you don't have to prepare for a disaster, just own a gun and get a directory of the members of your local Mormon church...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Encyclopedia of Mormonism article on [Emergency Preparedness](http://eom.byu.edu/index.php/Emergency_Preparedness) explains that this practice is about simple pragmatism.  It really has little if anything to do with eschatology; rather, the concept that members should maintain a stored supply of food is based on the simple reality that disasters and emergencies, both personal and wide-scale, do happen, and often without warning.

A person who has a long-term supply of food on hand is much better prepared to weather various disasters, ranging from a sudden loss of a job or unexpected medical expenses to societal disruptions such as natural disasters, riots, truckers' strikes or other conditions that make shopping for food difficult.

The recommended target given by the church is to have a year's supply of essential food saved up.  The EoM article references a 1980 General Conference talk by Ezra Taft Benson, then of the Quorum of the Twelve Apostles, which can be found [here](https://www.lds.org/general-conference/1980/10/prepare-for-the-days-of-tribulation?lang=eng).  In the talk, however, he states that this has been the counsel of the church "for over forty years."  (Which would most likely place the origin of the idea in the 1930s, most likely during the Great Depression, which makes sense. If anyone can find a source to date this counsel back that far, feel free to edit it in here.)

Comment: jinx!  We keep doing this alot...

Comment: @AffableGeek This happens with me and Mason all the time, too. And for the record, it's a blizzard today where I'm at, and we're kind of snowed in. The grocery stores were *packed* yesterday, and some food wasn't available. On a practical note, it seems wise to simply keep food on hand. (And rotate through the supply regularly.) And, this is the most correct answer so far.